# How to close pop up window in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, web-application

Below is my Selenium Webdriver script. When I run this script my website is opened but the popup window is also opened. How do I close this popup window so the script can continue?  Take a look on screenshot also.

```
package com.angara;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestAngaraWeb {

   public static void main(String[]args){

      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.angara.com");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li/a")).click();


   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see no screenshot

Comment: I attached a screenshot (it's a public website).  As you can see from the screenshot, this is not a new browser window.

Comment: I think the solution is a simple as locating the "X" at the top of that "window" and clicking it.

Comment: Knowing common terminology for browser windows can help you in the future.  Popup generally refers to a completely new browser window and is what people will assume if you use that term.  This is an inline add or popover within your existing web page.

Answer (score 5):

As user246 commented, you can write a method to locate the 'X' on the popup and click it if found.  Then you can define a custom method to locate an element on the page, something like this (kind of pseudo code):

```
myFindElement(String xpath)
{
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(path))
    }
    catch (ElementNotFoundException e){
        if !closethepopup(){print ('Element not found')}
    }
    catch (GeneralException ge){
    }
}
```

Within your closethepopup() method, you can choose to add some logic to return false if the popup is not found

Answer (score 4):

- To close popup- first you need to check which one is the active window in your application (Popup or main window).
- If popup is active then you can use `driver.close();` OR
- If the main window is active (Focused), then you need to use window
  handler to close this popup.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
Driver.SwitchTo().frame("Fancybox-frame");

Driver.findElement("enter your xpath to close popup").click();

Driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\all\\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.angara.com/");
Thread.sleep(5000);

for (String winhandle: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winhandle);
    System.out.println("Window Switch");        
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[span[contains(text(),'Close')]])[1]")).click();
}
```

Try this out, this should help you out.

Comment: Could you please add some details about the code, what is it doing and how could it help the OP? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this really worked for me-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.angara.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popsubform']/a/img")).click();
```

Try this out... hope this will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="popsubform"]/a/img")).click();
```

This should look for the "X" on the pop up and close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code to close a pop window by clicking on **[X]**.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
```

change this thing as per your use `@class`